# Airflow Sensor pokes callable only once at run time

Tags: python, airflow

When running a PythonSensor task in my DAG, it only pokes the script once while it should be doing it every 60 seconds. Therefore the task gets stuck in Running indefinitely. This is the task:

```
my_task = PythonSensor(
    task_id='my_task_id',
    python_callable=my_python_callable,
    poke_interval=60,
    timeout=60*15,
    dag=dag)
```

And the `my_python_callable` function:

```
def my_python_callable():

    try:

        validation_output = requests.post(...) 

        validation_output_json = json.loads(
            validation_output.content)

        if validation_output_json['is_valid'] == False:
            raise ValueError(validation_output_json['error'])
    
    except ValueError as e:

        print(type(e))
        print(e)

        send_error(str(e))

    return True
```

When triggering the DAG, the only log I get related to poking actions is:

```
[2023-01-11, 10:05:53 GMT] {python.py:72} INFO - Poking callable: <function my_python_callable at 0x7f942fcd2d40>
```

Shouldnt it show one of those every 60 seconds?

Thank you

Answer (score 1):

Your sensor will always finish after the first poke because all paths end up returning `True`:

- In case a `ValueError` is raised in the `try` block, it's handled in the `except` block, but not re-raised (assuming `send_error()` handles the error without raising an exception?), or returning `False` to indicate the sensor it should try again. After the except it returns `True` and your sensor will therefore finish after the first poke.
- In case no `ValueError` is raised, it returns `True`.

You should also see a message like this in the logs, telling you the sensor condition was met, and therefore it when into the "success" status:

```
Success criteria met. Exiting.
```

After `send_error()` you can return `False` to indicate the sensor condition wasn't met and it should try again.

Comment: Let's say that the `request.post` takes 10 minutes to receive the response. Then, `PythonSensor` won't be sending the first poke after 10 minutes right? I made the change you suggested but still have the same issue. Maybe I should create a global `validation` variable initiated as False that sets to True when the POST request has succeded? Then PythonSensor would read that `validation` every 60 seconds

Comment: Incorrect. Airflow will retry `poke()` until it returns `True` or until `timeout` is reached (15 minutes in your code). The first `poke()` is called immediately upon starting the task. If your desired `requests.post` response is given after +-10 minutes, then that will be the +-10th call of `poke()` (with a `poke_interval` of 60 seconds). Also, no need to add complexity and create a global `validation` variable. Simply returning `True` or `False` will do.

Comment: I changed my function to the following

`def my_python_callable(): try: (...) elif validation_output_json['is_valid'] == True: return True // except ValueError as e: (...) return False`

The last `return False` is outside of the try/except clause.
Same issue. Am I missing something? Thanks for your help on this Bas